# Why isn't my CSS being bundled into the app?

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, webpack, sass

I am trying to start a new project in vue.js, scss and webpack (server side is express.js, TS). Transferred configs from the previous project where everything worked. Everything looks right in my opinion. The build is successful... But browser does not apply my styles.
I do not understand what I set up wrong!

app.js:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
window.Vue = require('vue');

import './scss/index.scss'

import Signin from './Signin.vue'

const app = new Vue({
    render: h => h(Signin),
    el: '#guest-entry',
});
```

Signin.vue:

```
<template>
  <div id="signin-page">
    <h1 class="title">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur</h1>
    <h3 class="subtitle">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Possimus tenetur sit dicta repudiandae maxime ex corporis provident quos, minima, dolor cum eligendi veniam! Ut ab minus ad voluptatem, totam fuga!</h3>
  </div>
</template>
```

index.scss:

```
@import 'variables';

#signin-page {
    .title {
        text-align: center;
        color: $red;
    }
}
```

webpack config:

```
const path = require('path');
const VueLoaderPlugin = require('vue-loader/lib/plugin')

module.exports = {
  entry: {
    admin: ['babel-polyfill', './client/admin/app.js'],
    user: ['babel-polyfill', './client/user/app.js'],
    guest: ['babel-polyfill', './client/guest/app.js']
  },
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'client/static/js/'),
    publicPath: '/js/',
    filename: '[name]/bundle.js',
    chunkFilename: '[id].chunk.js'
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['*', '.js', '.vue', '.json'],
    alias: {
      'vue$': 'vue/dist/vue.esm.js',
      "@": path.resolve(__dirname, "client"),
      "@@": path.resolve(__dirname, "node_modules")
    },
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.vue$/,
        loader: 'vue-loader'
      },
      {
        test: /\.(woff(2)?|ttf|eot|svg)(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'file-loader',
            options: {
              name: '[name].[ext]',
              outputPath: 'fonts/'
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.js|mjs$/,
        use: {
          loader: 'babel-loader',
          options: {
            presets: ['@babel/preset-env']
          }
        },
      },
      {
        test: /\.(scss|css)$/,
        use: [
          'vue-style-loader',
          'css-loader',
          'sass-loader'
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.svg$/,
        loader: 'svg-inline-loader'
      }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new VueLoaderPlugin()
  ]
};
```

In Firefox:
[Dev tools](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NWfMf.png)
[Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MbpT9.png)

Comment: the browser says that there are no stylesheets on the page

Comment: Then the issue is with your app config.

Answer (score 0):

I just replaced **vue-style-loader** to **style-loader** and it worked.